# Running Loop over several excel files

Tags: r

I am currently trying to import ~100 excel files with facility inspections, titled "Facility-Inspection Month-Inspection Year" (e.g., County Hospital-February-2020). Each file has a column for the month (either this year or preceding year before the inspection, if month>=inspection month) and then an untitled variable for category. There are 43 rows. I want create a final table, reshaped long and appended for all facilities, having extracted the name of the facility as a variable and then identifying the correct year using a variation of the last three lines of the loop.

```
           Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
A          0  1   2   3   5   2     7  0  0    1  1   7
B          1  4   2   2   6   8     9  1  4    6  1   7
C
...
```

I am running into a variety of problems:

1. Assigning the title to the category variable without it simply producing a list of that category variable has not been possible (lapply is my latest erroneous attempt, producing an "'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]"). This is hindering my reshape attempt of course.
2. My separate function is giving me error saying that "no applicable method for 'separate' applied to an object of class "character".

There might be other errors present. Any help is appreciated.

```
#Setting up environment
path="C:/Files..."
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
data_files <- list.files(path, pattern=".xlsx$",)
monthabbrev=month.abb
monthcount=c(1:12)
shortmonth<-cbind(monthabbrev,monthcount)
monthname<-month.name
inspectionmonthcount<-c(1:12)
fullmonth<-cbind(monthname,inspectionmonthcount)

#Running Loop of Interest
dfList <- lapply(data_files, function(x) {
  if (file.exists(x)) {
    assign(x,                                   
           readxl::read_excel(paste0(path,
                           x)))
    lapply(data_files, setNames, c(1, "category"))
    x<-x %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -c(category), names_to = "month", values_to = "count")
  x$siteplace<-x
  x$siteplace<-gsub('.xlsx', '', x$siteplace)
  x$site<-x$siteplace%>% 
    separate(x, c("Name", "inspectionmonth", "inspectionyear"), sep = "-")
  merge(x, shortmonth, by.x="month", by.y="monthabbrev")
  merge(x, fullmonth, by.x="inspectionmonth", by.y="monthname")
  x$Year<-with(x, ifelse(monthcount<inspectionmonthcount, inspectionyear, inspectionyear-1))
  
  }
})
 
allfacilities <- do.call(rbind, dfList)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave some specific sample of the data.  Manually use `sample <- readxl::read_excel` on a single file.  The use `dput(head(sample))` and paste the output into your question.  Also give the exact file name of this sample excel file.

Comment: the file is identical to that as seen above but with 43 rows. I didn't want to include all of the data to clog the post. I included an example name above.

Comment: If you include a sample of the data using `dput(head(sample))`, then it will not take up much space at all because `head` will shorten it greatly.  People who answer your question can copy and paste it and help you make workable code.  Answerers can test that their code works before pasting it.  They can run your code to see where your problem is.  Right now, you are asking people to type in by hand your data, or to invent a way to generate it.  Even then, there might be a slight difference in the data structure that is not apparent from the printed console output that you gave.

Comment: Also, you say that one of your problems is with the naming of the columns.  This will be easy to diagnose from the output of `dput`.  It is very difficult to solve this problem if we have to pfaff about with your printed data.